# RPM with Java version dependency that yum seems to think it can meet with a different version

Tags: java, rpm, yum

We have a pom.xml building an RPM with the following :

```
 <requires>
 <require>jre &gt;= 1.8.0</require>
 </requires>
```

The resulting RPM seems to include the dependency but yum thinks it can satisfy the JRE >=1.8.0 requirement with JDK 1.7

```
# yum deplist app-core
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
package: app-core.noarch 0.1.0-1
  dependency: /bin/bash
   provider: bash.x86_64 4.2.46-19.35.amzn1
  dependency: /bin/sh
   provider: bash.x86_64 4.2.46-19.35.amzn1
  dependency: jre >= 1.8.0
   provider: java-1.8.0-openjdk.x86_64 1:1.8.0.77-0.b03.9.amzn1
   provider: java-1.7.0-openjdk.x86_64 1:1.7.0.99-2.6.5.0.66.amzn1
```

So, on a machine with only Java 1.7 installed, the app-core will install. When it should try to upgrade/install Java for me.

Comment: You may have more luck on Super User.

Answer (score 1):

After much Googling, I found this : http://programmingquirks.com/java-8-rpm-dependency/
Which suggests I need :

```
            <requires>
                 <require>java &gt;= ${jdk-version}</require>
            </requires>
```

(Java instead of JRE)